# DataGrip/PhpStorm is not connecting to MySQL DB, error: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I was using PhpStorm as my code editor and DB client both. It was working fine. But suddenly it stopped working. Deleting connection and then add new data source with absolute correct database credentials, but still it's not being connect. 
Then I thought it's a problem with PhpStorm, so I downloaded DataGrip, but it has the same issue. I am being able to connect with the same database by same credentials using SequelPro.

Here is what I am getting when I click apply button. When I click the "Test Connection" button it's shows an infinite process `connecting to database` running in background.

[image]

I have no idea what's going wrong suddenly with JetBrains products about DB. I am not 100% sure about exactly after which activity, I am getting this issue. I am using the latest version of PhpStorm and DataGrip (version 2017.3.4 Built on 17 January 2018) both.

My idea.log is as bellow:

[image]

Comment: Well ... `com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException` does not tell anything useful. How did you get that error window -- did it showed itself or you clicked on that blue `view` link on the bottom part of the screen? What's the full error (check `idea.log` via `Help | Show Log in XX`)? Since it's happening with both products ... have you restarted your Mac since then? It helps for any OS not just Windows :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This error window is being shown up when I click the view link. I have checked the idea.log also. When I click the test connection button, I got this log as you are seeing in the updated question.

Comment: I do not see any exceptions at all. No idea what else to suggest based on the info provided so far (except filing a ticket at JetBrains Issue Tracker)

Comment: Yeah, a programmer feels most helpless when something doesn't work but no informative error message for it. Have you filed a ticket?

Comment: No. I do not see any visible clues and unable to provide any additional details (it's happening on your side and I have no idea on what you have got there, what your recent actions were etc)

Comment: Have you filed a ticker to JetBrains, Imran?

Comment: Yes, I have filed a ticket. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `/etc/hosts` file had no record `127.0.0.1 localhost` for some reason.

For more investigation detail see [DataGrip issue DBE-5801](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5801/DataGrip-PhpStorm-is-not-connecting-to-MySQL-DB-error-com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In your Data Sources and Drivers window: select your db connection item.
2. Click [MySQL] link after the [Driver:] label
3. Remove all items in [Additional files:]
4. Done!

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is fixed long ago. As I filed a ticket on Jetbrains they help me out to fix the issue. Actually it was due to my foolishness with the `/etc/hosts` file.